# Parsing with json and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I've the following php page:

```
<?php 
$library=
'{"closets":[
             {"id":"001","theme":"literature","shelves":
                                                           {
                                                            "books":    [{"id":"b1","genre":"english Literature"},
                                                                     {"id":"b2","genre":"arabic literature"},
                                                                     {"id":"b3","genre":"french literature"}  
                                                                        ]
                                                           }
             },
             {"id":"002","theme":"comedy","shelves":{
                                                      "books":[{"id":"b11","genre":"english comedy"},
                                                               {"id":"b22","genre":"arabic comedy"},
                                                               {"id":"b33","genre":"french comedy"}  
                                                              ]
                                                     }
             },
             {"id":"003","theme":"history","shelves":{
                                                       "books":[{"id":"b11","genre":"english history"},
                                                                {"id":"b22","genre":"arabic history"},
                                                                {"id":"b33","genre":"french history"}  
                                                                ]
                                                      }
             }
            ]

}';

$literature=$_POST["literature"];
$comedy=$_POST["comedy"];
$history=$_POST["history"];

$library = json_decode($library, true);
$literatureBooks = $library['closets'][0]['shelves']['books'];
$comedyBooks     = $library['closets'][1]['shelves']['books'];
$historyBooks    = $library['closets'][2]['shelves']['books'];

if($literature)
{
    echo $literatureBooks;
}
elseif ($comedy){
echo $comedyBooks;
}
elseif($history){
echo $historyBooks;
}

?>
```

and the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#literature").click(function(){

$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'jsonTesting.php',
    data:{/*don'tknow what to write*/},

    success: function(data)
    {
        for (var i in data){
            $("#books").append('literature Books are'+data[i]+<'br/'>);
        }
    }


});
  });   
$("#comedy").click(function(){

$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'jsonTesting.php',
    data:'/*dont know what to write*/',

    success: function(data)
    {
        for (var i in data){
            $("#books").append('comedy Books are'+data[i]+<'br/'>);
        }
    }


});
}); 
$("#history").click(function(){

$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'jsonTesting.php',
    data:'/*dont know what to write*/',

    success: function(data)
    {
        for (var i in data){
            $("#books").append('history Books are'+data[i]+<'br/'>);
        }
    }


});
}); 
});
```

the program goes like this: when I hit the literature button all books of theme literature are displayed and so on for comedy and history. My problem is with the data in ajax. I'm asked to parse the object library and exclude the books of theme literature, comedy and history and place them in the data. how could that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User question is not clear enough. I think this is want you want.

You can go with jQuery Ajax request

```
$.post("jsonTesting.php",{"literature":1},function(data){
     //on success
},"json");
```

And in php use isset() for checking whether a post variable is set.

```
if(isset($_POST["literature"]))
     $literature=$_POST["literature"]
```

The entire code

Make this change to php code

```
if($literature)
{
     echo json_encode($literatureBooks);
}
elseif ($comedy){
     echo json_encode($comedyBooks);
}
elseif($history){
     echo json_encode($historyBooks);
}
```

The javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#literature").click(function(){
    $.post("jsonTesting.php",{"literature":1},function(data){
        if(data)
        {
            for (var i=0;i<data.length();i++)
            {
                $("#books").append('literature Books are'+data[i].id+" "+data[i].genre+<'br/'>);
            }
        }  
    },"json");
});
$("#comedy").click(function(){
    $.post("jsonTesting.php",{"comedy":1},function(data){
        if(data)
        {
            for (var i=0;i<data.length();i++)
            {
                $("#books").append('Comedy Books are'+data[i].id+" "+data[i].genre+<'br/'>);
            }
        }  
    },"json");
});
$("#history").click(function(){
    $.post("jsonTesting.php",{"history":1},function(data){
        if(data)
        {
            for (var i=0;i<data.length();i++)
            {
                $("#books").append('history Books are'+data[i].id+" "+data[i].genre+<'br/'>);
            }
        }  
    },"json");
});
});
```

Comment: can u plz edit my javascript, im new to ajax and dont know where to write the code above

Comment: still not working and i have to have ajax it is a must

Comment: sry i didnt know that  $.post is an ajax im new to ajax the error is at : if($literature) it's telling me that this variable is undefined

Comment: there is a syntax error in :
  $("#books").append("literature Books are"+data[i].id+" "+data[i].genre+<'br/'>);

Comment: try $("#books").append("literature Books are "+data[i]+"<br>");